# Set UIContextMenu for WKWebView links

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

[image]

How can we set a custom context menu for links within WKWebView?

You can set the context menu on an item by doing something like this:

```
    let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
    someItem.addInteraction(interaction)
```

and adding the `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` delegate:

```
 func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { (_) -> UIMenu? in
            let shareAction = UIAction(title: "Send to Friend", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { _ in
                // Pressed
            }
            let menu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [shareAction])
            return menu
        }
        return configuration
    }
```

How can you use a custom context menu when a user holds on a link in a WKWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `contextMenuConfigurationForElement` UI delegate method for your `WKWebView` e.g.:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    webView?.uiDelegate = self
}

extension ViewController : WKUIDelegate {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, contextMenuConfigurationForElement elementInfo: WKContextMenuElementInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (UIContextMenuConfiguration?) -> Void) {
        let share = UIAction(title: "Send to Friend") { _ in print("Send to Friend") }
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
          UIMenu(title: "Actions", children: [share])
        }
        completionHandler(configuration)
    }
}
```